# Check if a line intersects a cube (3D)

Tags: algorithm, math, coordinates

In a 3D cartesian coordinate system, given the vertices of a cube and the points of the ends of a line, I would like to check if the line passes through the cube (touching the vertices doesn't count). How could I do so?

Comment: Is the cube axis-aligned?

Comment: In the case that the cube is not axis-aligned, it is advisable to apply a spatial rotation to make it so.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson Yes the cube is axis aligned

Answer (score 1):

Using the parameteric equation of the line segment `PQ`, we establish the system of inequations

```
0 < t < 1
Xm < Xp + t Xpq < XM
Ym < Yp + t Ypq < YM
Zm < Zp + t Zpq < ZM
```

or, temporatily assuming `Xpq, Ypq, Zpq > 0`,

```
              0 < t < 1
(Xm - Xp) / Xpq < t < (XM - Xp) / Xpq
(Ym - Yp) / Ypq < t < (YM - Yp) / Ypq
(Zm - Zp) / Zpq < t < (ZM - Zp) / Zpq
```

This system admits a solution iff

```
max(0,(Xm-Xp)/Xpq,(Ym-Yp)/Ypq,(Zm-Zp)/Zpq) < min(1,(XM-Xp)/Xpq,(YM-Yp)/Ypq,(ZM-Zp)/Zpq)
```

If the inequation holds, the `t` values of the endpoints of the intersection are given by the `min` and the `max`.

Now, if `Xpq < 0`, it suffices to swap `Xm` and `XM`, and if `Xpq = 0`, the second inequation reduces to `Xm < Xp < XM`, and `t` is unbounded (`-∞<t<∞`). Similar reasoning on `Y` and `Z`, so there are nine cases to be considered.

---

Another way to look at the problem is that we stretch space by three linear transformations on the coordinates so that the segment `PQ` gets normalized to `(0, 0, 0)-(1, 1, 1)`, and the limits of the cube are recomputed accordingly. Then we get the simple system

```
 0 < t < 1
X0 < t < X1
Y0 < t < Y1
Z0 < t < Z1
```

---

A complete discussion of the special cases (segment in a face, crossing an edge, along an edge, through a vertex, just touching by an endpoint...) is out of the scope of this answer and is highly dependent on the use case.